# Proxy in mobile device not working device wide like vpn works

Tags: ios, proxy, dns, vpn

I am not sure what is the reason of this.
When I am using a vpn on my ios device any geo restricted mobile app i can access with the use of vpn, but when i am using a proxy (http/socks5) it is only working when browsing web with browsers, but when trying to access the geo restricted mobile app its not being accessed.

What is wrong, and how I can use a proxy similar to the vpn ?

Thank you everyone in advance for taking time to read this and helping out.

Comment: A VPN operates at the network layer in iOS and all traffic is carried over the VPN. An app doesn't need to do anything in order for its traffic to be carried by the VPN. Proxy settings are not used by all networking frameworks and the networking code in the app needs to specifically use the proxy settings. Not all do

Comment: thank you for informing.
Is there any way we can force an app to use proxy ?